# Dell 620 display is too bright to use

Tags: laptop, video, display, multiple-monitors, dell-latitude

I have a Dell D620 with a display problem. In windows 7 the display seems to be too bright, the text is broken up, the only way to see the mouse is at a very oblique angle.  Changing the brightness with fn and brightness control has little/no effect.  When I put it in high contrast mode I can see all the colors, but any windows pictures etc are still useless.  I cannot get it to connect to an external monitor via VGA port or via a USB-VGA connector.

Comment: Why can you " I cannot get it to go onto an external monitor via VGA port"? What happens if you try?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.screentekinc.com/Dell_Latitude_D620--14.1-inch--1440x900-wxgaplus-laptop-lcd-screen.shtml (from which I get no compensation) has replacement screen sets for the D620.